What is the difference between solubility and dissociation?
my chemistry textbook says that BaSO4 is a strong electrolyte so it must dissociate completely in its aquaous sol. but it is also a sparingly soluble salt. My Professor told me that the amount of BaSO4 that will end up dissolving will all get dissociated. What is that something that happened differently with the BaSO4 molecules that dissolved and dissociated?

Why did your research about solubility and dissociation fail? // What do you mean by BaSO4 molecule? BaSO4 is a ionic compound. // Dissociation applies rather to molecules like H2SO4 or CH3COOH.

Solubility and dissociation have no relations together. Sugar is soluble in water and is not dissociated

Note that the better counterpart to dissociation is dissolution (both are phenomena). The counterpart for solubility (or solubility product) would be a dissociation constant (both are properties).

Solubility is not the concern here. Whether the compound is soluble is partially soluble, it will always dissociate, in this case $\ce{Ba^2+}$ and $\ce{SO4^2-}$. If only any compound is completely insoluble, the lattice don't break down and the ions don't get to interact with the aqueous medium, hence no dissociation.

@NilayGhosh But that would end up with two types of dissociation. One, that is dissolution and the other one that is not.

IUPAC Goldbook: Dissociation :  1/     The separation of a molecular entity into two or more molecular entities (or any similar separation within a polyatomic molecular entity). Examples include unimolecular heterolysis and homolysis, and the separation of the constituents of an ion pair into free ions. 2/  The separation of the constituents of any aggregate of molecular entities. //
In both senses dissociation is the reverse of association.

IUPAC Goldbook:Solubility The analytical composition of a saturated solution
, expressed in terms of the proportion of a designated solute in a designated solvent, is the solubility of that solute. The solubility may be expressed as a concentration, molality, mole fraction, mole ratio, etc.  //  IUPAC Goldbook: Dissolution The mixing of two phases with the formation of one new homogeneous phase (i.e. the solution).

Dissociated generally implies that the "molecules" break up into ions in the solution.(Molecules in quotes because ionic solids don't really have individual molecules in the solid phase.)
Dissolved can be due to either "dissociated" as noted above or that the actual molecules in the solid become solvated.
Thus:

Table sugar dissolves, but does not dissociated in water.
Table salt (sodium chloride) both dissolves and dissociates in water.


Solubility is how easy something can be dissolved in water. Something with a high solubility will more easily dissolve in water.
When something dissolves in water, it mixes with the water and then precedes to interact with the water. Sugar dissolves in water because it mixes and then forms adhesion forces with water - it forms hydrogen bonds with water which are stronger than the hydrogen bonds between water
Mostly used for covalent acid molecules and for bases but can be applied to salts, if something dissociates, it dissolves and then splits up into ions which attract and get surrounded by water molecules (hydration).
E.g Hydrochloric acid dissociates into hydronium ions and chloride ions as it reacts with water molecules donating its proton causing the Hydrochloric acid to split up.
When salt dissociates, the lattice breaks down / splits up and the Ions hydrate - form bonds with water.

Ions in salts are already splitted up, they just separate from each other during their hydration process. There are no BaSO4 molecules in BaSO4(s) ionic lattice.

HCl does not dissociate into H+ and Cl- ions. It reacts with water to form hydrated H3O+ and Cl- ions.  Gas phase reactions are homolytic not ionic.

@jimchmst And dissociation constants do not exist. ;-)
